# Should I expect Python sqlite3 user defined functions to persist in a SQLite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I register a user defined function:

```
conn.create_function("geocode", 4, geocode)
```

The function is used in a trigger, and the trigger fires correctly after an insert, but the function isn't found:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: geocode
```

My understanding of this usage pattern may be wrong, is it possible to persist Python functions in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) says:

> If an application uses more than one database connection then application-defined SQL functions must be added to each database connection separately.

And how could your Python code persist when you can open the same database file later on some other machine?